# Container color cover Listile color

Tags: flutter

I want to have a grey container with a list of listiles and the selected one in blue but the container color cover the listtile color. How can I fix it?

```
   Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.5.w, vertical: 2),
                  margin:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.5.w, vertical: 0.5.h),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surfaceVariant),
                  child: Column(children: [
                    Text(
                        DateFormat('MMMM')
                            .format(
                                DateTime.parse(event.date!.toDate().toString()))
                            .toString(),
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 8.h,
                      child: ListView.separated(
                          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return DateTile(
                              weekDay: DateFormat('d')
                                  .format(week[index])
                                  .toString(),
                              date: weekNames[index],
                              isSelected: index == 4 ? true : false,
                            );
                          },
                          separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return const SizedBox(width: 0);
                          },
                          itemCount: 7),
                    )
                  ])),
```

DateTile is a custom tile witch has blue color if it is selected
Here is the code, just a ListTile with round borders

```
class DateTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String weekDay;
  final String date;
  final bool isSelected;
  const DateTile(
      {super.key,
      required this.weekDay,
      required this.date,
      required this.isSelected});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 14.w,
      child: ListTile(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
        tileColor: isSelected
            ? Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primaryContainer
            : Colors.transparent,
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 0, 8, 0),
        title: Text(date,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1!.copyWith(
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer)),
        subtitle: Text(weekDay,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1!.copyWith(
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here some pictures shows I want
[image: This is what I have]

[image: This is what I want]

Comment: could you include DateTile too?

Comment: Try changing the height of the `SizedBox` to larger

Comment: also could you include an image of your current result? @Mus

Comment: what do you mean by `but the container color cover the listtile color`? how do you differ selected one with unselected one?

Comment: By index in the list: isSelected: index == 4 ? true : false,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEM**

You are handling the color change in the wrong `Widget` and wrong `params` in your `DateTile` at:

```dart
tileColor: isSelected
? Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primaryContainer
: Colors.transparent,
```

This only changes the color of the tile children's properties and not the background color. To implement change in background color used, first delete this line of code.

**SOLUTION**

After deleting the `tileColor` line of code, change the `SizedBox` to `Container` and add your color property there. DONE!!

If this doesn't work, let me know please.

Below is an example I made with a similar codebase.

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final week = [
    {"name": "Mon", "date": 26},
    {"name": "Tue", "date": 27},
    {"name": "Web", "date": 28},
    {"name": "Thu", "date": 29},
    {"name": "Fri", "date": 30},
    {"name": "Sat", "date": 31},
    {"name": "Sun", "date": 01},
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
              color: Colors.grey,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "December",
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 100,
                    child: ListView.separated(
                      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      separatorBuilder: (_, i) => const SizedBox.shrink(),
                      itemCount: week.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return DateTile(
                          weekDay: week[index]["name"].toString(),
                          date: week[index]["date"].toString(),
                          isSelected: index == 4 ? true : false,
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DateTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String weekDay;
  final String date;
  final bool isSelected;
  const DateTile({
    super.key,
    required this.weekDay,
    required this.date,
    required this.isSelected,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width) / 7,
      color: isSelected ? Colors.blue : Colors.transparent,
      child: ListTile(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 0, 8, 0),
        title: Text(date, textAlign: TextAlign.center),
        subtitle: Text(weekDay, textAlign: TextAlign.center),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```